# Is it possible to use a menu resource in a ViewHolder created context menu?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my Android application I have implemented a context menu that is created in my RecyclerView ViewHolder class. It is done programmatically using the Menu "add" method.

My research has failed to identify how I can build these context menus based upon a menu resource, rather than programmatically.I really would like to do it this way and would appreciate any pointers to appropriate examples or documentation.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Yes it's possible: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#context-menu

Comment: I understand that information, however, as I mentioned I am creating the menu in my ViewHolder class and "getMenuInflator" is not available to me, unless I am missing something.

Comment: `getMenuInflater` is a convenience method. You can create one as needed using the `MenuInflater(Context context)` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, one step closer. I can create an Inflater but when I call the "inflate" method there is an error that says "Incompatible Types,Required Android.View.Menu, Found void ".